# The pronunciation of "cовсем" vs "со всем"

Tags: произношение

Here is a verse by Marina Tsvetaeva:

> Совсем ушел. Со всем — ушел.

([Надгробие](https://www.culture.ru/poems/35301/nadgrobie))

My way of pronouncing "cо всем" is exactly the same as the way I pronounce "cовсем," but that makes it impossible to distinguish the two sentences. If I had to emphasize the difference between the two sentences, I'd pause between *Со* and *всем*, which seems unnatural (at least to me). Is there any difference in the pronunciation of these two phrases? Are the two *o*'s pronounced in the same way? Is there a pause between *cо* and *всем*?

Comment: Oh, my favorite poet, she liked to play with words like that. That was intended, actually. So yes, you can emphasize, but we would never know as we don't have recordings of her voice (which saddens me you cannot imagine how much).

Comment: In English a "purple people eater" can be "an eater of purple people" or "a people eater that is purple". If we mean the former, then we can say the first two words quickly, pause, then speak the final word at normal speed with extra emphasis. In any spoken language, we constantly modulate the prosody subtly to enhance clarity, and unsubtly if needed to eliminate outright ambiguity, and we do so automatically and semi-subconsciously. Surely Russian is no different. And here the ambiguity is deliberate, so using unusual prosody to voice the poet's intention is kind of the whole point, no?

Comment: @ghostarbeiter I am not a Russian native speaker - I believe that my pronunciation is often good enough to make me understand but it doesn't mean that it is the way Russians speak. In that case if I say "Со всем" in the way I speak (not in the context of the poem) people understand me but maybe there is some subtle difference. For instance I read that not all unstressed *o*'s are pronounced in the same way while I don't make any difference - in practice it "works" (people understand me) but I was wondering if we are in such a case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in pronunciation between *со всем* and *совсем* whatsoever, or, the way the kids on the internet put it these days, *от слова совсем*. There's no pause or accent or anything.

That's hardly surprising, given that *совсем* (the adverb) is etymologically *со всем* (the phrase) in a very thin disguise.

Answer (score 3):

To distinguish the two sentences, I would add a little pause where the dash is. The pause, along with a bit of a rising tone just before it, is a common way to indicate ellipsis:

- Маша любит красное вино, а Катя↗ – белое.
- Совсем ушел. Со всем↗ – ушел.

Answer (score 1):

The second phrase has a noun omitted. It means something like "со всем имуществом - ушёл", "со всеми вещами - ушёл", "ушёл - и забрал с собой всё".